# Magento 2 checkout_cart_product_add_after Observer setWeight not working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0

I am working with Magento 2.0.10, I have created an observer to set the product price and weight posted from the products details page using a custom attribute. In the below example I am trying to set a static price and weight. For the price attribute its working correctly, but I am not able to set the weight. The quote item is giving the actual product weight while calculating shipping. Even if I change the observer event to **sales_quote_item_set_product**, it is not working at all for changing weight.

And even now I have tested with Magento 2.1 as well, but it isn't working at all

In events.xml and I am creating an observer like below

```
<event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
    <observer name="checkout_cart_product_add_after_customprice" instance="Test\Slider\Observer\Customprice" />
</event>
```

And script that i have used in my observer is working like this

```
$item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
$item->setCustomPrice(10);
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice(10);
$item->setWeight(10);
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
```

Comment: It would be saving under field row_weight, not sure why but if you can adjust to use it at required places by using $item->getRowWeight() in your calculations..

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this using a plugin:

**app/code/Product/SetWeight/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Product_SetWeight',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Product/SetWeight/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Product_SetWeight"/>
</config>
```

**app/code/Product/SetWeight/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item">
    <plugin name="product_set_weight" type="Product\SetWeight\Plugin\ItemWeight"/>
</type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Product/SetWeight/Plugin/ItemWeight.php**

```
<?php

namespace Product\SetWeight\Plugin;

class ItemWeight
{
    public function afterSetProduct(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $subject, $result)
    {
        $weight = "3";
        $result->setWeight($weight);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**This solution is of course missing custom logic to determine which products should be changed and how!**

Hope I've been able to help people revisiting this thread.

Answer (score -1):

Finally , i have found the solution. May be it's not the best solution , but it works

I have just commented line number **422** with script

```
->setWeight($this->getProduct()->getWeight())
```

coming inside **setProduct** function in the below file

```
/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Item.php
```

And its working for me.

Comment: You know that changing code in a file that's in `vendor` will be overwritten as soon as a newer version of that file/module is available and installed. I have to be honest, I don't know the answer right away, but I don't think this will be the solution you're looking for.